# Producing a Dialog that will be dismissed automatically

Tags: android, dialog

is it possible to create a `Dialog` that will be dismissed automatically after some time if it doesn't have any user interaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a Handler to automatically dismiss it.

In the class members:

```
private final int CANCEL_DIALOG = 1;
private Handler mHandler;
private Dialog mDialog;
```

In onCreate():

```
mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback()
{
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        if(msg.what == CANCEL_DIALOG)
        {
            mDialog.cancel();
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

On the button you use to open the dialog (or whatever system you use):

```
mDialog.show();
mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(CANCEL_DIALOG, 5000);
```

Essentially after 5 seconds, the dialog will close after it has opened using this code.

Comment: In the handleMessage() I put some Log . That function not executing

Comment: If it works then the dialog will be closed exactly after 5 seconds, whether or not dialog is getting interaction. If dialog is getting interaction it should not be dismissed....Is that possible....

Comment: It should work, is the Log in the if statement, or at the start of the handleMessage()? Is the Handler created in your Activities onCreate() method (overridden)? If you want to make it so that when a Dialog receives interaction the timer stops, then you can call mHandler.removeMessages(CANCEL_DIALOG);

Comment: Ok thanks .. it works well for me.....Now I need to check whether the second one is working...Thank you....

Comment: I have a list_view inside the Dialog. Then wat should I write inside the OnScrollListener??  Pls reply

Comment: mHandler.removeMessages(CANCEL_DIALOG);
     mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(CANCEL_DIALOG, 5000);

Answer (score 2):

I got it finally by using `Handler`.

```
mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback()
{
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        if(msg.what == CANCEL_DIALOG)
        {
            mDialog.cancel();
        }

        return false;
    }
});

mDialog.show();
mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(CANCEL_DIALOG, 5000);
```

Inside `Dialog` I have a `ListView`. In the `scrollListener` of that `ListView` I put:

```
mHandler.removeMessages(CANCEL_DIALOG);
mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(CANCEL_DIALOG, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an activity as dialog box and then finish it after some time(as you want).

Answer (score 0):

```
dialog.show();
final Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
    dialog.dismiss(); // when the task active then close the dialog
    t.cancel(); // also just top the timer thread,otherwise, you may receive a crash report
    }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

As simple as that.

```
 new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                 //Your AlertDialog.cancel
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
final Timer t = new Timer();

            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                public void run() {

                    dlg.dismiss(); // when the task active then close the 
                                    // dialog(here we are dismissing the dialog)

                    t.cancel(); // also just top the timer thread,
                                // otherwise, you may receive a crash report

                }

            }, 2000);
```

Here we are creating the Timer object and scheduling the timer for 2 sec.once 2 sec over ,then it automatically calls run(), in run() we will write the logic to dismiss the dislog

Comment: Some explanation would probably be helpful

Comment: Copy pasting the answer of the other answer-er in the same post doesn't seem fair.